# Can't install Active Admin for Ruby on Rails: "Sprockets::FileNotFound..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I installed a new rails app locally, then added the active admin gem and ran rake db:migrate and then the installas per the instructions. I'm also using powder.

When trying to access the admin area at mysite.dev/admin, I get the following:

> Sprockets::FileNotFound in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new
>
> couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
>     (in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js:2)

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've ran `bundle install`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should set in your gem file : gem 'jquery-rails', "2.3.0" to fix the jquery-rails gem version to 2.3.0
The last update ( 3.0.0) remove the jquery-ui files and cause that issue :

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui' (in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js:2)
```

That should fix your issue for now. You can also get the last version of Active Admin from github that fixes your issue.

But I would advice to change

```
gem jquery-rails
```

in your gemfile to :

```
gem 'jquery-rails', "2.3.0"
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you, I will try that tonight!

Am I right in saying that once I've done a `bundle install` it then caches a version of active admin, or whatever bundle I've installed, on my local machine? If so, how would I update my local copies of bundles from time to time? is there a set way / best practice approach to this?

Comment: Yes everytime you run bundle install that will install new gems but keep the current version installed on your computer. If you want to update your gems you can run bundle update and that will update all the gems where the version is not specified in your gemfile.

Comment: If you're in my shoes and this didn't work: make sure you don't have the gem `jrails` installed, it will conflict with `jquery-rails` with no helpful error to tell you so.  I was upgrading to Rails 3.

Answer (score 8):

I've updated to last version (0.6.0) and I had the same problem.
Instead of downgrade my jquery-rails or install the gem directly from github, I change `//= require active_admin/base` in my in active_admin.js for:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require active_admin/application
```

Comment: This is worked for me but I had to add `jquery-ui-rails` to my Gemfile.

Comment: This is the best solution to the problem.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work for me and I've ran out of time to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
rails generate active_admin:assets
```

it generates:

```
/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
```

That file contains only one line which is to pull in the base js file from the Gem:

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

active_admin/base (in the Gem) is only 4 lines, one of which is causing the problem:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require active_admin/application
```

The workaround I chose is to change the contents of your project's /app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require active_admin/application
```